# libzydis_linux_amd64.syso: file format not recognized; treating as linker script go-zydis

Tags: go, disassembly

i have a error when i want to install go-zydis

error:

```
[bryton@BRYTON scrap]$ go get go.jpap.org/zydis
# go.jpap.org/zydis
/usr/bin/ld:/home/bryton/go/pkg/mod/go.jpap.org/zydis@v0.0.0-20210718235710-17c1dd869f7f/libzydis_linux_amd64.syso: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/usr/bin/ld:/home/bryton/go/pkg/mod/go.jpap.org/zydis@v0.0.0-20210718235710-17c1dd869f7f/libzydis_linux_amd64.syso:1: syntax error
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné le statut de sortie 1
```

In the readme it says you have to install git-lfs, which I did but it doesn't work :/

I am in arch linux. Can you help me please ^^?

Link of library: https://github.com/jpap/go-zydis